# emergency на русском языке?

Tags: переводы

Я нашел разный перевод для "emergency" - "экстренный случай" и "чрезвычайная ситуация". Как правильно перевести?

Я имею ввиду ситуацию когда с кем-то что-то случилось и надо вызывать скорую помощь. Кажется что я нашел значит "exceptional circumstances" а не что я имею ввиду.

Comment: https://www.etymonline.com/word/Emergency - я тут смотрю. Я бы перевёл как непредвиденное, непредусмотренное происшествие. Хотя чрезвычайная ситуация может лучше. Чрезвычайная - то есть сверх необычная. Короче что-то чрезвычайное, по отношению к событию или происшествию.